# Is there a way to Bubble sort user input in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, user-input, bubble-sort

I would like to allow the user to input numbers or generate random numbers. Then I would like to allow him to Bubble sort the numbers that are displayed (either the randomly generated ones or the numbers the user inputted).  Any suggestions on how to bubble sort that specific array, even though it isn't defined beforehand? Here is the code I have so far:

Thanks for the help

```
main.js

function randomNumbers() {
var num = document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = Array.from({length: 30}, ()=>   Math.floor(Math.random() * 100));

}


function bubbleSort(arrayToSort) {
  var swapped;
  do {
    swapped = false;
    for (var i = 0; i < arrayToSort.length - 1; i++) {
      if (arrayToSort[i] > arrayToSort[i + 1]) {
        var temp = arrayToSort[i];
        arrayToSort[i] = arrayToSort[i + 1];
        arrayToSort[i + 1] = temp;
        swapped = true;
      }
    }
  } while (swapped);
}


function createList() {
    
    var number = prompt("Enter a maximum of 20 numbers, seperated by a comma");
    document.getElementById("outputnumber").innerText = number;
    
    }
 
function createSortedArray() {
var list = createList();
bubbleSort(list);
document.getElementById("sort").innerText = list;
  
  }
```

```
index.html

<body>

  <h1>Javascript Assignment</h1>
  <hr>
  <h3>Computer Platforms and Operating Systems - CIS 1102</h3>


  <p>Choose one of the following to create a list of numbers:</p

  <br>
  <p>
    <h4>i) Input Your Own Numbers</h4>
  </p>
 

 
  <p>
    <button onclick="createList(); " id="display" >Input Numbers</button>
  </p>

  <h4>ii) Random Generator</h4>
 
 
  <p>
  
    <input type = "button" onclick = "randomNumbers();" value = "Generate 30      Numbers" />
    
  </p>
  
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  
  <p id ="outputnumber"></p>
  <p id="demo"></p>


  <br>
  <hr>
  <br>
  <br>

  <p>Choose one of the following to sort the numbers:</p>

  <p>
      <button onclick="createSortedArray()" id = "bubble">Bubble sort</button>
  </p>


  <p>or</p>

  <p>
      <button onclick="" id = "bubble">Selection sort</button>
  </p>

  <p id="sort"></p>

  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>

  <hr>



</body>
```

Comment: PS format your code. Also, `</hr>` is an invalid tag

Comment: refer https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort

Comment: The question is unclear for me. You posted a code with a bubble sort function and you're asking how to sort an array. What exactly is your question?

Comment: You have an apparently okay bubble-sort implementation in your code, that can be used for sorting any array of numbers. What you don't have is an array of numbers, as you have text in a textbox. Use `string.split()` and `parseInt()` (in a loop or `array.map()`) to get an array of numbers from the input or your own generated string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would not call `createList` again in the function `createSortedList`, as at that time we may assume the user already entered a list, or created a random one.

Instead let `createSortedList` *read* the list that was written to HTML earlier on, split it by comma, and convert each element to number data type:

```
function createSortedArray() {
    // Don't call createList(), instead read the array from the document:
    var list = document.getElementById("outputnumber").innerText.split(",").map(Number);
    bubbleSort(list);
    // It probably makes sense to write the result to the same HTML element:
    document.getElementById("outputnumber").innerText = list;
}
```

I would also get rid of the `demo` HTML element, as you would want the randomly generated list to work as input for the sorting just like the manually input list. So in the function `randomNumbers` replace "demo" with "outputnumber". And drop the variable `var num` in that function -- it plays no role.

So:

```js
function randomNumbers() {
    document.getElementById("outputnumber").innerHTML = Array.from({length: 30}, ()=>   Math.floor(Math.random() * 100));
}

function bubbleSort(arrayToSort) {
  var swapped;
  do {
    swapped = false;
    for (var i = 0; i < arrayToSort.length - 1; i++) {
      if (arrayToSort[i] > arrayToSort[i + 1]) {
        var temp = arrayToSort[i];
        arrayToSort[i] = arrayToSort[i + 1];
        arrayToSort[i + 1] = temp;
        swapped = true;
      }
    }
  } while (swapped);
}


function createList() {    
    var number = prompt("Enter a maximum of 20 numbers, seperated by a comma");
    document.getElementById("outputnumber").innerText = number;
}
 
function createSortedArray() {
    var list = document.getElementById("outputnumber").innerText.split(",").map(Number);
    bubbleSort(list);
    document.getElementById("outputnumber").innerText = list;
}
```

```html
<p>Choose one of the following to create a list of numbers:</p>

<button onclick="createList();" id="display">Input Numbers</button> or
<button onclick = "randomNumbers();">Generate 30 Numbers</button>   
<p id ="outputnumber">4,1,2,3</p>
<button onclick="createSortedArray()" id = "bubble">Bubble sort!</button>
```

Comment: That answered my question! Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

You need to return the array from `randomNumbers` and `createList`.
In `randomNumbers` it would be `return num` at the end of the method and in `createList` it would be `return number.split(",")`. Then just pass the returned array to your `bubbleSort` method and it should work